# Error when trying to compile Pro*C programs in Linux

Tags: c, linux, database, oracle, embedded-sql

I am practicing with a `Pro*C` program and `SQL` and I have the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlca.h>

char user_id[20]="test/test"
char emp_name[20];

main()
{
    EXEC SQL CONNECT :userid;
    printf("Connected\n");

    EXEC SQL DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name
        FROM badge;

    EXEC SQL OPEN emp_cursor;

    printf("Employees---------------");
    EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break;while (1)
       {
          EXEC SQL FETCH emp_cursor INTO :emp_name;
          printf("%s\n", emp_name);
        }

    EXEC SQL CLOSE emp_cursor;
    EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;

    exit(0);
}
```

It simply retrieves all the names from a table called `BADGE`:

```
CREATE TABLE BADGE  
(
    badge_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),   
    surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    birthday DATE
);
```

However, when I try to compile the source I have the following error:

> proc test.pc
>     proc: symbol lookup error: proc: undefined symbol: kgsuglo_

Can anyone help me out with the error?

Comment: Which version of Oracle/Pro*C? Instant client or full install? Is your environment set up properly - PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH set and exported?

Comment: PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are correctly exported. Is there a way I can use to check the version of Oracle/Pro*C and the type of the installation? I am using an already existing test environment

Comment: Does `proc` display the banner, which includes the version and system default path - or is it failing before it even gets that far? If not what does the`sqlplus` banner show? Failing that your ORACLE_HOME might tell you, along with the entry for that in your PATH (whether it has ORACLE_HOME/bin).

Comment: `proc` fails before displaying the banner, while `sqlplus` correctly works

Comment: OK, but what version info does SQL\*Plus show? Not sure how you get Pro*C to fail that early though, without any further info shown.

Comment: Use ldd to inspect loaded depencies (*.so). You might be loading the wrong versions or the loader might not be able to locate alll dependencies.

Comment: The `sqlplus` version is 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with `instantclient-precomp-linux.x64-12.1.0.1.0.zip` and solved it by upgrading to `instantclient-precomp-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip`